# How to determine if element 'x' is in sorted array in Ω(log(n)) run time?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, binary-search-tree

How can I decide if element `x` is in the sorted array `A` in `Ω(log(n))` run time?

My initial answer: we use binary search, and create a decision tree which can show that its height is at least log_3(n), hence Ternary tree with height `h` has `3^h` leaves , therefore 
log_3(n) ∈ Ω(log(n)).

Comment: Hmm, how are you doing a binary search on a ternary tree?  A binary search is the correct approach, though.

Answer (score 0):

The decision tree is a good instinct.  Now imagine not actually creating the tree, but performing the same search through it anyway....